# With windows authentication, The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed, when calling IsInRole

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have my asp.net web server setup to use windows authentication.

It is authenticating just fine with my current logged in user.

I can verify this by viewing ...

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

And I can verify that I am authenticated by viewing...

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

However, when I call the .IsInRole function I get the trust relationship error...

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("accounting")
```

I have found online references to problems with supplying domain name with the role name (domain\accounting), but I still get the same error.  Any suggestions on where to look or troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it seems that if you are referencing a Role that doesn't exist then you get the trusted domain error.

The error went away and the code functioned just fine when I changed from ...

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("accounting")
```

to the actual group name ...

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("rsi_accounting")
```

Comment: I'm running into this problem as well. Did you actually have multiple domains/forests with (or without) trust between them?

Comment: I had this issue when running two load-balanced servers in the same domain - one could handle a non-existent group, the other couldn't! Never worked out why...