# "Trust relationship between ... and the primary domain failed" in MVC5 Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP .NET MVC5 application in which I am **not** using Windows Authentication.

Everything was working fine until I tried running the application outside of the Domain in which it was being developed and (for whatever reason) got a:

```
The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
```

when I'm trying to do `User.IsInRole("Admin")`.

I am using custom `Identity`, `Role`, `IdentityStore`, `RoleStore`, etc. from .NET's [`Identity`](http://www.asp.net/identity) and I can see that the User and Role data is being retrieved from the (MongoDB) database correctly.

There are plenty of questions regarding this issue, but they're from people who **want to** use Windows Auth. and impersonation in their MVC applications:

- [With windows authentication, The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed, when calling IsInRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625509/with-windows-authentication-the-trust-relationship-between-the-primary-domain-a)
- [How to configure Windows Authentication / Impersonation + IIS 7 + MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665710/how-to-configure-windows-authentication-impersonation-iis-7-mvc)
- [The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/497586/the-trust-relationship-between-the-primary-domain-and-the-trusted-domain-failed)
- [My.User.IsInRole("Role Name") throws a Trust Relationship error on Windows 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75f7964b-c90f-487d-ae0c-82678dbe0c6e/myuserisinrolerole-name-throws-a-trust-relationship-error-on-windows-7?forum=vblanguage)

So why exactly am I getting this `SystemException` if I'm not using Active Directory and (as far as I know) not doing anything that might depend on the PC's domain? Am I missing some configuration (either in my `Web.config` or IIS Express)?

### EDIT:

Ok, so narrowing it down a bit...

My `User.IsInRole("Admin")` line is inside an `if()` statement in my `_Layout.cshtml` View (i.e., to know what to show in the nav. bar depending on the role).

I now know I only get the error above when no user is authenticated and I'm not in the domain I used for dev. If I place a breakpoint on that line, I can see that the `User` object is is a `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity` and its underlying `Identity` is `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity`.

On the other hand, if the user is authenticated, then the `User` object and ts `Identity` are `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` and `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity`.

Why is it using Windows Identity at all (when unauthenticated) and how can I disable it?

Comment: Somewhere, you're still attempting to connect to the domain. Is it possible that `<authentication mode="Windows" />` is in your web.config?

Comment: I wish it was that, I've already CTRL+F'd for that and "windows". No luck.

Comment: Is there something in your role provider that depends on Active Directory?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity (which has IUser, IUserStore, etc...), Microsoft.Owin.Security, System.Security.Claims...

Comment: Added an EDIT to the question that might help narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Sadly, you're kind of on a wild goose chase. Check the global.asax, and heck the entire solution for any references to `WindowsIdentity` or `Windows` and see if that yields anything.

Comment: For @user1987392, but mainly for others with this issue, searching for windows is not sufficient, as [windows is the default mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/532aee0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), at least in .Net 4.

Comment: FWIW, all of the sudden I found myself unable to log into my EPiServer site using windows credentials. When I switched from from forms authentication to windows, I got this error in the browser. It turned out something must have been corrupted because after re-adding my machine to our domain, it was fixed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So, based on my EDIT, I've modified my `_Layout.cshtml` so that instead of having

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))  {...}
```

I have

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin")) {...}
```

which seems to solve the problem.

I believe the problem was that `ASP .NET Identity` uses an [empty `WindowsIdentity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091157/how-do-you-login-authenticate-a-user-with-asp-net-mvc5-rtm-bits-using-aspnet-ide?rq=1) when no user is authenticated and when I try to check for the User.IsInRole, then it will try to check the roles of a WindowsIdentity against an Active Directory that I don't have. Obviously I should first check if the user is even logged in before attempting to check its roles, so *mea culpa*.

But, even though the change above seems to fix my code, I'd be very interested in knowing more about this behavior: why is it using an empty `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity` when no user is authenticated. I'll accept any answer which explains that.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue regarding this. The trust relationship error results from calling `IsInRole('somerole')` when the Claims on the Identity does not contain that role, the Identity is Windows, and that group does not exist in the primary domain, and some trust issue between another domain exists. I never resolved my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518243/user-isinrolefake-group-results-in-the-trust-relationship-between-the-prima

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus if I recall correctly, in my case the problem was that doing `User.IsInRole()` if the user wasn't authenticated would throw an error. I wasn't using Active Directory at all so unfortunately I don't really know how to help.

Comment: no worries. Was just providing the link back to the other question in case others found this one instead.

Comment: Yup, MVC5 seems to use a windows identity when the user is unauthenticated, checking for isAuthenticated fixes this

Comment: Didn't fix for me.

Answer (score 12):

I've had this issue - It failed for me if I tested an active directory group that didn't exist.

Make sure you're using a group that exists!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue with Asp.Net Core 3.1 **with** Windows Authentication, but this thread came up first when searching the internet. I ended up resolving the issue by decorating the controller class declaration with the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
[Authorize]
    public class SetupController : Controller
```

Hope this is helpful for someone that **is** using Windows Authentication and is having the same error.

Comment: Thanks for trying, and I upvoted for that, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

We were having this same issue on a new production server. Using the Identity Framework and restricting access to a specific directory with a web.config file denying any unauthenticated users. When unauthenticated users tried to access a page in this directory that contained any `User.IsInRole("RoleName")` code, they were getting the "Trust relationship..." error.

None of the fixes mentioned in other SO answers worked for us.

Turns out we just had to enable Forms Authentication in IIS - problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The "trust relationship between the primary domain and the workstation has failed" error message usaully requires that the [computer be removed from the domain and then rejoined](http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/fix-the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-domain-failed/). Now there are a few ways to do this. As included in the link above, are instructions on how to do so either on the computer displaying the error or remotely. You can also do so in Active Directory and in PowerShell.

Comment: I wasn't using Active Directory, but thanks for your answer - it may be useful for people who do and get here with the same error message.

Comment: For others ...this error seems to be a generic message that Microsoft uses it doesn't always mean it needs to be rejoined

Answer (score 0):

```
<authorization>
            <allow roles="pri\Domain Users" users="pri\domain_user" />
            <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

- make sure that you have the above line in your web.config file and complete the user field with the correct user name.

Answer (score 0):

I've just resolved this in our systems, unfortunately, none of the other suggestions worked for me. The issue was caused by an orphaned SID in a network folder the code was attempting to access. Once removed it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same scenario with custom Authentication Module and the same error when doing IsInRole. The highest ranking solution (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && ...) did NOT help. So, I played quite a bit with it. Finally I found that I had to remove a  (preCondition="managedHandler") attribute from my module declaration in web.config file. So, instead of:

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules>
          ...
          <add name="CompanyAuthentication" type="Company.Authentication.AuthHttpHandler" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
```

I would have to have:

```
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules>
          ...
          <add name="CompanyAuthentication" type="Company.Authentication.AuthHttpHandler" />
    </modules>
```

That did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the whole membership provider configuration tags were missing. After i copy those from one our previous apps, it worked fine.

```
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
  <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="ABC.ABCModels.ABCRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I am not using  `User.Identity` but rather `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`

So when I approach this line of code:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("admin");
```

That's where I will encounter the same error message of:

`The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.`

There are two cases why I encountered the same issue and of course the fixes I made:

- I was disconnected with my VPN. This will look for the role that doesn't exist since I am not connected with my VPN and not connecting with my AD accounts.
- If I am connected with my VPN and the role `admin` doesn't exist based on my code above, it will certainly trigger the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth sharing how I've fixed on my situation as these answers helped me to figure it out.

We were allowing/restricting access to pages via `web.config` and this was happening before touching any code (so it didn't matter where the breakpoint was, the error was coming).

Since this was not amazing too, I've decided to implement this validation in the code manually instead of using the `web.config` one.

our `web.config` used to look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="10,5"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

We've changed to:

- Created a page (called restricted page) that inherits from Page
- This page has a protected variable called `RequiredAccessLevel`
- The OnLoad of the page we check if the user is in the role of the `RequiredAccessLevel` and if it is not, we redirect to a custom AccessDenied page
- Made the pages that should have this restriction inherit from `RestrictedPage` instead of `Page`
- On the constructor of the pages that are inheriting from `RestrictedPage` we set the access level necessary

Like this:

**RestrictedPage.cs**

```cs
public class RestrictedPage : Page
{
    protected int[] RequiredAccessLevel { get; set; } = { };
   
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RequiredAccessLevel.Length > 0)
        {
            var allowed = false;
            foreach (var ral in RequiredAccessLevel)
            {
                if (Page.User.IsInRole(ral.ToString()))
                {
                    allowed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!allowed)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
        }
       

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

}
```

**Example.cs**

```cs
public partial class Example: RestrictedPage
{
    public Example()
    {
        RequiredAccessLevel = new[] {10};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What was confusing in our case was:

- this error message started appearing out of the blue one day
- the Role claims were present on the claims principal
- some roles would work, others would raise that exception

At some point in time, all these roles must have existed in the Windows domain, and then some point later some were removed for whatever reason.

Because we are managing user roles within the application we don't care whether or not the role exists in the Windows domain.  In fact, its better that the roles exist only within our application.

For this reason, it was appropriate to switch from `user.IsInRole("SomeRole")` to `user.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "SomeRole")`.

We then encapsulated this authorization code within an extension method.

```cs
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static bool HasClaim(this ClaimsPrincipal user, string claim) =>
        user.HasClaim(c => c.Type == claim);

    // More extension methods for specific authorization checks ...
}
```

**This solution will not be appropriate in the case where role assignment needs to be managed in the Windows domain.**  Instead, I'd recommend catching the exception and re-raising it with an appropriate error message indicating that the requested role is missing from the Windows domain. Then, when this re-raised exception appears in your logs, you'll have the necessary information to rectify the problem quickly.