# The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed in sql server job

Tags: sql-server

I just use BULK load from server A by using SQL query in SQL Server but when I try to execute the job in SQL Server Agent I got the error like "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed."

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think the issue is with the user account that is used by SQL Agent. Can you provide mode details about accounts used to run SQL Jobs and SQL Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Trust relationship between ... and the primary domain failed" in MVC5 Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765626/trust-relationship-between-and-the-primary-domain-failed-in-mvc5-authentic)

Answer (score 0):

Might be the User account password expired is used to connect SQL Server Agent. Which user account using, that you can identify by below steps

1. Open Services.msc
2. Right click and SQL Server Agent and take the Properties
3. Go to Logon tab. There you can see the user using to connect.
4. Change the password with new and save. And try to restart the SQL Server Agent